# Promoted Links: Enlarge to 300px

Tags: promoted-links

[image]enter image description here[image]I used the code to scale Promoted Links (to make the Tiles smaller)and changed the values but the part with the hidden text, remains visible.

div.ms-promlink-body {
                height: 300px;
            }

```
        div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
            height: 310px !important;
            width: 310px !important;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > span {
            height: 300px !important;
            width: 300px !important;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img {
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
            height: 300px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 16px;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeCollapsed, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeExpanded {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00000;
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 16px;
            min-height: 36px;
            min-width: 97px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -0px;
        }

        li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 3px;
        }
```

.ms-tileview-tile-content img {
    width:300px!important;
    height:300px!important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see my comment) to understand what I have added

```
<style type="text/css">
            div.ms-promlink-body {
                height: 300px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
                height: 310px !important;
                width: 310px !important;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > span {
                height: 300px !important;
                width: 300px !important;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img {
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
                height: 300px;
                padding: 0;
            }

            li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
                font-size: 11px;
                line-height: 16px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeCollapsed, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeExpanded {
                padding: 10px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00000;
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 16px;
                min-height: 36px;
                min-width: 97px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                position: absolute;
                top: -0px;
            }

            li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
                font-size: 11px;
                line-height: 14px;
                padding: 3px;
                display:none; /* removing the small text */
            }

          .ms-tileview-tile-content img {
               width:300px!important;
               height:300px!important;
           } 

      </style>
```